# RequireJS incorrectly loads scripts from URLs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS to load dependencies. This is how my config looks like:

```
'use strict';

require.config({
    paths: {
        jQuery: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min'
    }
    shim: {
        jQuery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jQuery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

When I run my static website, in the console there are messages like this:

```
GET http://*myhost*/js/backbone.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1896
Uncaught Error: Script error for: backbone
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166
GET http://*myhost*/js/jQuery.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1896
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jQuery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166
GET http://*myhost*/js/underscore.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1896
Uncaught Error: Script error for: underscore
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:166
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

As you can see, RequireJS ignores the fact that I'm providing URLs for CND and tries to look for modules locally.

However, sometimes RequireJS works fine - it loads modules from URLs. Some kind of lottery over there. Worth to mention that it happens only on my remote development server - that is when I access my website over web. When I run my website locally, RequireJS always loads modules from CDN perfectly fine. Weird, any ideas why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

This is how I start my application:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

**main.js (where config is loaded)**

```
define(['config', 'router'], function(Config, Router) {
    var router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: Please show us how your configuration is loaded and how you start your application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main module starts with this:

```
define(['config', 'router'], function(Config, Router) {
```

This tells RequireJS to load `config` and `router` but does not specify the *order* in which they should be loaded. If `router` depends on modules that use the CDNs you've listed in your configuration and assuming that `config` is not among `router`'s dependencies, then you would indeed get intermittent loading failures. When `config` happens to load before `router` everything is fine. If `config` loads after `router`, then all hell breaks loose. The simplest way to fix this problem would be to move your configuration into your `main.js` file. You could have the `require.config` call before the `define` call, and you'd obviously no longer list `config` among the dependencies.

If moving the call to `require.config` does not work for you because (for instance) you need to share `config` among multiple pages then this would also do the trick:

```
define(['config'], function () {
    require(['router'], function(Router) {
        var router = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
});
```

The code above ensures that `config` is loaded before anything else.

Your configuration is also wrong in the following ways:

1. You must always refer to jQuery as `jquery` because jQuery (for better or for worse) hardcodes its module name as `jquery` all lower caps. I've run tests with using `jQuery` instead of `jquery` and got erratic results.
2. jQuery 2.0.3 does not need a shim. Having a shim for it only confuses RequireJS.

Comment: Thank you for response. I updated my question, do you need more information?

Comment: Does your `router` module have `config` in its dependencies? (I guess not but I thought I'd ask.)

Comment: No, definitely not :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I see is the likely explanation for what is going on with your code.

Comment: Working like charm! Thanks so much!